# Do you now have to install the Skype App on mobiles to get to the actual video-chat page?

Tags: google-chrome, android, skype-for-web

The Question
On a phone using Android and Chrome, I'm signed in to Skype, I easily access my account-details-page, but cannot get to the actual video-chat page ( something called something like go.skype ) ?

I am using Skype on the web on Chrome-browser ( the latest version ), but I am not using the Skype App.

- There is the little-drop-down-box made of 3 or 4 little horizontal lines, and there is the Skype drop-down-box with a little arrow next to it. Both drop-down-boxes give exactly the same options, and none of the options in the drop-down-box menu lead to the actual video-chat page ( something called something like go.skype ).
- Have there been any recent changes to Skype on mobiles that you can no longer get to the actual video-chat page ( something called something like go.skype ) without installing the Skype App.
- I did try typing "go.skype", and I think I got to a "go.skype" page, but it was not the actual video-chat page and did not seem to have any links leading to it.
- I tried the web.skype.com page, but it never loads.
- I am using the latest version of Chrome, and my mobile ( bought 2016 ) handles youtube pages effortlessly, so it should be more than fine for Skype.

Comment: Instead of the date when you bought your mobile, add the the brand model, the Android and Chrome versions.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://web.skype.com/ using Google Chrome for Android.

Note: By default, Google Chrome works on mobile mode. I just created a Microsoft Account, and Skype user profile using my Mac Mini. Then, on my Android Xiaomi, I opened https://web.skype.com and created a new meeting. It worked fine.

If it doesn't work, try changing Google Chrome to Desktop mode.

##### Google Chrome Help Center

Relate help article, just for reference.

- [Manage desktop mode settings](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/13514529?hl=en)

---

You haven't mentioned that you have reviewed the Skype system requirements. Here is the link to the corresponding webpage: [What are the system requirements for Skype?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10328/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-skype).

> ##### Skype for Web system requirements
>
> | Skype for Web |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | Supported web browser | Skype for Web is supported on most desktop and mobile browsers. You can [check your browser compatibility here](https://support.skype.com/faq/FA34904/). If your browser is not supported, you can [download Skype for your device](http://skype.com/download). |
>
> Note: Users on Windows 7 or Windows 8/8.1 may be able to sign in but may not receive the full experience of Skype for Web.

Adapted from [What browsers are supported for Skype for Web?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34904/what-browsers-are-supported-for-skype-for-web)

> It's easy to use [Skype on the Web](https://web.skype.com/) with most modern browsers. Check the table below to verify that your preferred browser is supported.
>
> | Browser | Platform | Messaging | Calling |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Google Chrome | Mobile | Supported | Supported |

The URL to use is https://web.skype.com/

Comment: Although I now got the "web.skype.com" link to finally load 'only' in "Desktop mode", it barely functions at all in terms of selecting and changing settings, and there is no Chat-Screen showing at all ( I am trying all the settings ), and I cannot find the setting for 'Making A Test Call', so my modern-smartphone ( from 2016 ) with the latest Chrome-Browser has as many problems with Skype as my antique laptop